# How do I depend on a crate within a Cargo workspace over git?

Tags: git, rust, rust-cargo

Given a [Cargo workspace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html) in one git repository that contains one crate `foo`, and another crate `bar` outside of that workspace, how do I depend on `foo` in `bar`? If `foo` were just a regular crate-within-a-git-repo, the following works:

```ini
foo = { git = "ssh://git@server/some/foo.git", ... }
```

And if `foo` were inside a Cargo workspace and it lives in a local directory, the following works:

```ini
foo = { path = "../../some-workspace/foo" }
```

But using `git = "ssh://..."` that points to a repository that contains a Cargo workspace, I am unable to specify the `foo` crate in particular.

It is not possible to combine `git = "..."` and `path = "..."`, since those are mutually exclusive.

In the [Specifying dependencies from git repositories](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies-from-git-repositories) chapter of The Cargo Book, it offers `branch = "..."`, `tag = "..."`, `rev = "..."`, but no "sub-crate's directory name, i.e. the name of the crate". There is a `package = "..."` specifier mentioned under [Renaming dependencies in Cargo.toml](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#renaming-dependencies-in-cargotoml) meant for importing a crate as something else. But it doesn't seem to double as the crate-within-a-workspace specifier.

Comment: What happens if you point the git URL to the subfolder, e.g. `ssh://git@server/some/workspace.git/foo`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your dependency name should have the name of the crate in the workspace. Cargo will search for it. Suppose the workspace foo has crate bar within it.

```
bar = { git = "ssh://git@server/some/foo.git", ... }
```

Not sure where this is documented, but there is a discussion here:

https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/10151

Comment: What if I need all crates in a workspace, do I really have to duplicate this line once for each member? And if I use a `rev` in them, when it is updated I have to update ALL these lines? It seems silly if this is the only way...